# ANDROID: Align dynamically created number pickers

Tags: android, alignment, numberpicker

I am creating an Alert Dialog with two number pickers and two textviews on top of each one to select month and year, and the textviews are just labels.
I am creating them dynamically because it seems easier to fill with the min and max options (couldn't do it with xml and layout inflator). I just can't make the two pickers (and their labels) to be centralized on the alert dialog box. They show on extreme left and extreme right, making it very ugly.
I am probably over coding this but here it is:

```
final NumberPicker np1= new NumberPicker(this);
    final NumberPicker np2= new NumberPicker(this);
    final TextView t1=new TextView(this);
    final TextView t2=new TextView(this);

             t1.setText("Month");
    t1.setTextSize(20);

    t2.setText("Year");
    t2.setTextSize(20);
             np1.setMaxValue(12);
    np1.setMinValue(1);
    np2.setMaxValue(2030);
    np2.setMinValue(2000);      
    np1.setValue(Month);
    np2.setValue(Year);

    RelativeLayout linearLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(20,20);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams numPicerParams1=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams numPicerParams2=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    numPicerParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF);
    numPicerParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    linearLayout.addView(np1, numPicerParams1);
    linearLayout.addView(np2, numPicerParams2);
    linearLayout.addView(t1,numPicerParams1);
    linearLayout.addView(t2,numPicerParams2);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Chose month and year.");
    builder.setView(linearLayout);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    { (...)
```

Comment: Can you post your xml?

Comment: @JohnWhite - I think he is creating everything dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
relativeLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);


RelativeLayout linearLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(20,20);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams numPicerParams1=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams numPicerParams2=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
numPicerParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF);
numPicerParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
linearLayout.addView(np1, numPicerParams1);
linearLayout.addView(np2, numPicerParams2);
linearLayout.addView(t1,numPicerParams1);
linearLayout.addView(t2,numPicerParams2);

relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
```

Comment: This will layer them on top of each other, won't it?

Comment: Looks like i can't use .addrule on relativelayout like this.Eclipse says that the method is undefined for the type RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML should look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month_text"
        android:text="Month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/month_picker"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/month_picker"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day_text"
        android:text="Year" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/month_text"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/year_picker"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/year_picker"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/month_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/month_text" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/year_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/day_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/month_picker"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will go inside a parent layout that is the body of your alert dialog.

Then, in code, you can do this:

```
NumberPicker monthPicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.month_picker);
NumberPicker yearPicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.year_picker);

monthPicker.setMaxValue(12);
monthPicker.setMinValue(1);
yearPicker.setMaxValue(2030);
yearPicker.setMinValue(2000);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do I inflate(call) the xml? And what goes into the body of the alert dialog?

Comment: [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) gives you a very clear path to building an `AlertDialog`, and you can set the body of the AlertDialog by calling `AlertDialog.Builder.setView(view)`. The view that is passed to this method would be the xml above, which is inflated using a `LayoutInflater`.